# Adding AES encrypt/decrypt to flask routes

Tags: python, flask

Say in the below Flask endpoint code, I need to decrypt the request data and encrypt the response

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def update_record(): 
    decryptedData = decrypt(request.data)   
    if decryptedData == '1232':
        response = {'status': True, 'message':'Success'}
        return encrypt(response)
```

Now i.e say if the given the encryption I would like to use is AES-256. I have 100's of such flask endpoints. Is it possible to create a encrypt/decrypt infrastructure such that I don't have to manually change each and every API's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@app.before_request` and `@app.after_request`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement encryption in your middleware when you receive a body and a key,from there you can return error or proceed to further business logic, the secret Key can be passed in the headers, you can have another header i.e. encrypted set to true/false to give more information about the payload, so that you support encrypted and non-encrypted payloads.
It's also same thing you can do with JWT based authentication.

Examples here.
[WSGI middleware to record requests and responses](https://gist.github.com/georgevreilly/5762777)
[flask JWT](https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/)